# Problems when removing checkbox from dialog, and open it agin the checkbox doesn't remove

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, checkbox, modal-dialog

When I add a card to the inbox list, then it is possible to double click on the card to open a modal dialog. In the dialog it is possible to add some checkboxes dynamically, and remove/delete them by clicking on the image TRASH.

The issue is lets say, I create 3 checkboxes and then want to remove/delete one of the checkboxes. After that I want to save the data and pressing save button. The dialog close. When I double click on the same card to open the dialog the checkbox I removed is still there.

Can some one help me to fix it ?

[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/AdiT/62QY8/103/)

HTML:

```
<!--Wrapper div-->
<div id="wrapper">
    <!--Inbox list and button to add a card-->
    <div id="inboxList" class="cellContainer">
        <p style="display: inline">Inbox</p>
        <!--Button to add a Card-->
        <input type="button" id="AddCardBtn" value="+ Add a Card..." />
        <hr class="fancy-line" />
        <br/>
        <!--Card div-->
        <div id="userAddedCard">
            <br/>
            <div></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<!--Modal Dialog-->
<div id="modalDialog">
    <form>

        <input type="button" id="Savebtn" value="Save" />
        <br />
        <br/>
        <label>Add checkBox</label>
        <br />
        <br />
        <input type="text" id="checkBoxName" />
        <input type="button" id="btnSaveCheckBox" value="_Ok" />
        <br />
    </form>
</div>
```

Jquery:

```
$(function () {
    // Click function to add a card
    var $div = $('<div />').addClass('sortable-div');

    var cnt = 0,
        $currentTarget;
    $('#AddCardBtn').click(function () {
        var $newDiv = $div.clone(true);
        cnt++;
        $newDiv.prop("id", "div" + cnt);

        $newDiv.data('checkboxes', []);

        $('#userAddedCard').append($newDiv);

    });

    // Double click to open Modal Dialog Window
    $('#userAddedCard').dblclick(function (e) {
        $currentTarget = $(e.target);

        $('.allcheckbox').remove(); // Remove checkboxes
        $('#modalDialog').data('checkboxes', []); /* Reset dialog checkbox data */

        /* Add checkboxes from card data */
        $.each($currentTarget.data('checkboxes'), function (i, checkbox) {
            addCheckbox(checkbox.name, checkbox.status);
        });

        $('#modalDialog').dialog({
            modal: true,
            height: 600,
            width: 500,
            position: 'center'
        });
        return false;

    });

    $("#Savebtn").on("click", function () {
        /* Copy checkbox data to card */
        $currentTarget.data('checkboxes', $('#modalDialog').data('checkboxes')); 

        $('#modalDialog').dialog("close");
    });

    // Add a new checkBox
    $('#btnSaveCheckBox').click(function () {
        addCheckbox($('#checkBoxName').val());
        $('#checkBoxName').val("");
    });

    function addCheckbox(name, status) {
        status = status || false;

        var container = $('#modalDialog');
        var inputs = container.find('input');
        var id = inputs.length + 1;
        var data = {
            status: status,
            name: name
        };

        var div = $('<div />', { class: 'allcheckbox' });
        $('<input />', {
            type: 'checkbox',
            id: 'cb' + id,
            value: name
        }).prop('checked', status).on('change', function () {
            data.status = $(this).prop('checked');
        }).appendTo(div); /* set checkbox status and monitor changes */

        $('<label />', {
            'for': 'cb' + id,
            text: name
        }).appendTo(div);

        $('<img />', { "src": "/Pages/Images/trashDialog.png", "class": "removeCheckBoxDialog" }).appendTo(div);

        div.appendTo(container);

        container.data('checkboxes').push(data);
    }

    // Remove dynamically checkBoxes
    $('#modalDialog').on('click', '.removeCheckBoxDialog', function (e) {
        $('#' + $(this).prev().attr('for')).remove();
        $(this).next('br').remove();
        $(this).prev().remove();
        $(this).remove();

    });  
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ignore my previous post here is a working version:
http://jsfiddle.net/62QY8/117/

Go through the code to see the changes but heres the biggy:

```
$('#modalDialog').data("checkboxes").splice(theIndex, 1);
```

Loop through the data array to find theindex that matches the same name of the one your removing.

Comment: Thank you very much. I want to ask you do you store the checkBox in this variable? var arr = $('#divboxs').data('checkboxes');

Comment: I find it easier to put an array into a variable then loop through it to find the index of the want you want to remove.

Comment: Okay. And one more question. Why the number 1 in .splice(theIndex, 1) ??

Comment: removes 1 item from the position given by "theIndex"

Comment: Hi again. I'm implementing an 'edit' field to the CheckBoxes. My issue is when I create one checkbox and name it eg. "Hallo". Then I want to edit it, and name it "Hallo World" instead, then save the data via Button. When I open the same card the checkBox is still named "Hallo", and not "Hallo World". I have tried fix it by my self by the similar solution like yours, where you put an array into a variable then loop through it to find the index of the want you want to override the text. But not succeeded. Can you please help ? I have a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/62QY8/125/

Comment: When you click on edit and amend the name your just telling it to update the text. Your using .data() which stores information in browsers dom like a cookie, which you can access using developer tools (f12). So your telling it to change just the text but then load the text from the data stored in the browser, it will override everytime, you need to update the data and then the text.

Comment: Hmm Can you please help me with that? I'm still in double how to do it by coding.

Answer (score 0):

Your storing the the checkboxes using .data() then removing them from the page but when you click the modal-dialog you access the .data() again. you need to also remove the element from the data see [.removeData()](https://api.jquery.com/removeData/)